# VBA + POWERPOINT WOMBO COMBO

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I used a macro to create a PwoerPoint slide from 0. But now, I need to add some informations.  I need to insert a title using the information on the cell $A$3, and concatenate with "(Histórico)".  The information on the cell is a variable according with the pivot. For example: in slide 1 I want A (Histórico). On the slide 2, B (Histórico), and A or B, or anything according with the cell A3.

This is the code:

```
Sub ExportarPPTX()

'Referenciando a Biblioteca Microsoft Powerpoint:
'1. No ambiente de Desenvolvimento VBA: Menu / Tools
'2. Click em Reference
'3. Desça até encontrar Microsoft PowerPoint X.0 Object Library, selecione a opção e clique em OK

Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application                 'Declarando as variáveis que serão usadas
Dim newPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject

On Error Resume Next                                        'Procurando instâncias
Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If newPowerPoint Is Nothing Then                                            ' Check whether PowerPoint is running
    Set newPowerPoint = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")              ' PowerPoint is not running, create new instance
    newPowerPoint.Visible = True                                            ' For automation to work, PowerPoint must be visible
End If
On Error GoTo 0

On Error Resume Next                                                ' Reference presentation and slide
If newPowerPoint.Windows.Count > 0 Then                                     ' There is at least one presentation
    Set newPresentation = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation                           ' Use existing presentation
    Set activeSlide = newPresentation.Slides _
        (newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)        ' Use active slide
Else
    Set newPresentation = newPowerPoint.Presentations.Add                            ' There are no presentations, Create new presentation
    Set activeSlide = newPresentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)               ' Add first slide
End If
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the macro so we can see how to help you.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: But unfortunately, in this code, it just create a new power point presentation from 0. I need this just one time, and after this, just making new slides instead of new presentations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you add a new slide.

```
Dim pptSlide As Slide 
Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout 

Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout 
Set pptSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(2, pptLayout)
```

Parameters of are .AddSlide(index of slide to be added, the layout of the slide)

Both parameters are required.

Answer (score 0):

And what about to insert the chart and the title ? For example, I have a slicer to choose the product, and then, it give me the chart. I need to write "Name Product A - (Historico)", and paste the chart in each slide. For many products...